# Connection Bigquery to Wix via extrenal connection

Tags: google-cloud-run, velo, spark-bigquery-connector

I followed this instruction to connect my Biquery to the WIX collection

https://dev.wix.com/docs/develop-websites/articles/databases/external-databases/google/integrate-your-google-cloud-platform-databases-with-your-wix-site

In the documentation, I need to define 3 secret keys

[image]

When the DATABASE_ID is the dataset_id as described

[image]

But unfortunately, the instance is not working and I got the following erorr:

```
TypeError: A dataset ID is required.
.BigQuery.dataset ( /usr/lib/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/bigquery/build/src/bigquery.js:1099 )
```

[image]

**instance eror**

```
Revision 'velo-external-db' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information. Logs URL: Open Cloud Logging  For more troubleshooting guidance, see
```